# Algorithm to find mutually correlated changes at various positions in the string over a set of strings

Tags: string, algorithm

I have a file with large number of strings. Every string is approximately 500 characters long. Every string has same length. I want to compare each string with all the remaining strings to find the position at which these strings differ. **My main aim is to find out correlated changes at various positions in the string i.e. if there is a change at position one then which are all the positions that has changed simultaneously**. **I have to also calculate the frequency of these changes as well**.Naive and simple approach would be to compare each string with every other string with two loops (i.e. one within other). This would be O(n^2). I am looking for more efficient approach.Possibly O(n). I am trying to do it with only one iteration.

Comment: What are you going to do with the comparisons? If you are interested in all `O(n^2)` comparisons you of course need to spend `O(n^2)` time anyway. So I expect you want to do certain queries, but it is not at all clear from your question what your goal is.

Comment: if you want the diff between all pairs of strings then you will atleast need O(N^2) iterations . please update your question if you intend to mean something else

Comment: I have updated the question. DO have a look at it.